# Looking to switch to LTS kernel on my ubuntu PC

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, no VM. I need to switch my kernel version to an LTS version (preferably 5.4, but I think 5.8 and 5.11 will work as well) to be able to install the RealSense SDK.

I have tried to boot from version 5.4 already in the GRUB menu at startup, but this caused ubuntu to freeze at boot and not start. How can I make the switch? All of the answers I've found are for VMs and won't work in my case.

Comment: kernel 5.4 is the initial kernel in Ubuntu 20.04, what version are you running now?

Comment: The kernel I have right now is version 5.15.0-46. I am wondering at one point in the past I upgraded to 5.15 when something required it. Now when I try to boot with kernel 5.4 from GRUB menu, ubuntu will not boot.

Comment: It may help if you explain why you want this old kernel.

Comment: I believe 5.15 might be the HWE kernel introduced with 20.04.5 - Pilot6's answer will work.

Comment: David, intel Real Sense Camera's SDK requires kernel 5.4 (or any LTS kernel). That's why I need to revert.

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
 sudo apt install linux-generic
```

Then boot with the 5.4 kernel using grub menu.

After that remove all 5.15 linux image, modules and headers using Synaptic.

Comment: Wow that worked. Spent way to much time doing not that haha. Thanks